# how to move http 400 request logs to diffrent log file in apache?

Tags: linux, apache, centos, apache2, system-administration

i want my apache request that is related to non 200 http response should log to diffrent log file. i tried this

```
LogFormat "%a %b %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %!200,304,302{Referer}i" browserlog
CustomLog logs/non200_logs browserlog
```

but it is displaying me all 200 response code in log file.

output i am getting like this ..

> - 64.147.20.134 - - [19/Mar/2015:05:56:32 -0700] "HEAD /PdfServerUpdate/ADP/Director.Xml HTTP/1.1" 200 - -
> - 66.209.107.58 - - [19/Mar/2015:05:56:32 -0700] "HEAD /PdfServerUpdate/Director.Xml HTTP/1.1" 200 - - 5580 64.147.20.134 - -
>     [19/Mar/2015:05:56:32 -0700] "GET /PdfServerUpdate/ADP/Director.Xml
>     HTTP/1.1" 200 5580 - 6983 66.209.107.58 - - [19/Mar/2015:05:56:32
>     -0700] "GET /PdfServerUpdate/Director.Xml HTTP/1.1" 200

please help me to sort out, what exactly parameter should i use in the httpd.conf file.

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you have to use %>!200, 304, 302 s instead of referer

Comment: Thanks for the reply..i used  LogFormat "%b %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %>!200,304,302{Referer}i" browserlog
    CustomLog logs/non200_logs browserlog
if i remove {referer}i then it throwing error to restart.. can you please paste the exact parameter that i can use in httpd.conf file..